# Failed to click on second button on webpage of intranet

Tags: javascript, html, css, vba

[image]

It doesn't have **id** element into second button elements except *type*, *value* and *onclick*;

**Below is my webUI code**

```
<input type="button" value="Download" 
onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1','Account_number$0')">
```

**Below is my VBA code**

```
Dim htmlDoc As HTMLDocument  
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer  
Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement  
Dim myURL As String  

On Error GoTo Err_Clear  
myURL = "url......................."  
Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer  
MyBrowser.Silent = True  
MyBrowser.Navigate myURL
MyBrowser.Visible = True
Do
Loop Until MyBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set htmlDoc = MyBrowser.Document

htmlDoc.all.txtAccNo.Value = "0" & "" & TextBox2.Value 
htmlDoc.all.ddlReasons.Value = "1"
htmlDoc.all.txtRequester.Value = TextBox3.Text 'Enter your password here
htmlDoc.all.txtMobNo.Value = "0" & "" & TextBox1.Value
htmlDoc.all.txtLandLine.Value = ""
htmlDoc.all.txtEmailAdd.Value = Range("E15")
htmlDoc.all.ddlRelation.Value = "3"
htmlDoc.all.button1.Click
```

**error in blow script of second button**

```
htmlDoc.getElementsByXpath("input[type=""button""]").Click
```

Please help me, how to automate this button?

Comment: not respond on your code :(
    htmlDoc.getElementsByXpath("input[type=""button""]")(0).Click

Answer (score 0):

When i run into this I try to find a unique attribute for the elm in question. The reason for this is that there may be other buttons on the page that you don't want to click. Looks like `onclick` and `value` are unique for the Download button. I chose `value`. Here's a seperate function (for clarity) that should work. It should click the first Download button found. You can set it to click a specific row's button by modifying the function.

```
Function ClickDownload(doc As IHTMLDocument) As Long
  On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  Dim elms As IHTMLElementCollection
  Dim elm As IHTMLElement

  Set elms = doc.getElementsByTagName("input") 'gather all input elms
  For Each elm In elms 'book through each input elm until we find a match
    If elm.Value = "Download" Then 'the elm.value "Download" seems unique enough
      elm.Click
      GoTo ErrHandler 'jump out, and be sure to set vars to nothing
    End If
  Next

ErrHandler:
  Set elm = Nothing
  Set elms = Nothing
  ClickDownload = err.Number 'silently return 0 if it did not fail
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks to find an attribute but still not responding on **second** button 

**Note:** It takes time to load _download_ button when click on first button **"View Bill"**

Comment: np. that sounds like a seperate question, but i'll say that it can get complicated to deal with load times. bring  in ie object WithEvents, and play around with DocumentComplete()'s URL, StatusTextChange()'s Text, form timer to call boolean function that looks for specific elements to exist before you deam the page to be complete (enough). good luck